# How to change Header title in navigationOptions from constructor in react-native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-tabnavigator, react-native-drawer, react-native-tab-view

In my react-native project I have use DrawerNavigator from which I navigate to SwitchAccount page. In SwitchAccount page I have use Tabs from react-native-tabs. Below is code where I use

```jsx
    render() {
      return (
     <View style={[styles.container]}>
      // Here _renderTab function return component based on selectedService
      {this._renderTab(this.state.selectedService)} 
      <TabBarContainer
          selectedService={this.state.selectedService}
          onTabChange={this._switchService}
        />
     </View>
    ); 
  }
```

When I click on tab then it change the state and then I get new component returned by _renderTab function. All works properly, but I want to change Header title based on the component returned by the _renderTab function.
What should I do? Is there any way to change Header title from constructor?
Below is my code for navigationOptions in SwitchAccount page. There I want to change title from constructor.

```jsx
    static navigationOptions = {
    title:'Filter',
    drawerLabel: 'Switch Account',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon
        name='md-switch'
        size={40}
        color='black'
      />
    ),
  };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to to use the navigation `params`. `navigationOptions` can be defined as a function (instead of an object), which receives an object containing the `navigation` object itself as one of its keys:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({ /* ... */ })
```

This allows you to set the title dynamically by reading a param from the `navigation` object:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam('title', 'DefaultTitle'),
    /* ... */
})
```

Within one of you components you could then call the `setParams` function on the `navigation` object to set the title:

```
handleChangeTab = (tab) => {
    /* Your tab switching logic goes here */

    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        title: getTitleForTab(tab)
    })
}
```

Note that the component must have been mounted by `react-navigation` in order to have access to the `navigation` prop, otherwise you'll either have to pass it from its parent or use the `withNavigation` HoC to wrap the component and have it receive the prop from there.

That said, have you considered using [Tab navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html)?

Comment: Thanks @juandemarco. Sir, your solution is 100% working.

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)

Comment: Hey @juandemarco I'm already use static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({ /* ... */ })
but it's not change the title, i want to change title based on the params i passed, ``` static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: navigation.getParam('providerName'),
        };
    }
 render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {console.log("@name", this.props.navigation.getParam('providerName'))} // i can get the name here
            </View>
        );
    }